# color picker is not selecting any color developed using html,javascript,css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftjH7.png)

When I select any color in the color picker it is not showing that selected color in the down. I'm new to `javascript`. Please any one help me.

Thanks!

Below is the code for the above image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>iro.js demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="half">
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half readout">


        <div id="values"></div>
        <div id="css"></div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/jaames/iro.js/master/dist/iro.js'></script>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And how should we be able to identify the problem based on your HTML only?

Comment: Add your css and javascript code here. It will be helpful

Comment: Can you explain at where error is occurs or what problem is face during run time like error or etc.